# Is there a wrapper (framework) around vsto for word and excel

Tags: excel, frameworks, ms-word, vsto, wrapper

I'm working with VSTO and the Interop Namespaces for a while now. For the most of its parts it is good (enough). But sometimes it seams realy ridiculous.

There are methods which return an object which has to be casted when it's obvious what they should return.

#### *Like this example to add a new worksheet:*

`sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(missing, application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, 1, missing);`

Other times you need to use the missing Type for method calls because there isn't a method overwrite for it. (*I know that's just a problem in C# and not in VB*)

#### *Like in this example to protect a excel sheet:*

`sheet.Protect(missing, true, true, true, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);`

My question is now:
Is there any kind of wrapper, framework, api, ... to avoid all these little inconveniences? (*Or any kind of framework which offers a few more convenient methods*)

Comment: SO is [not a recommendation site or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/140505). This question is off-topic here.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Type.Missing`? Are you using .NET 3.5 or lower or something?

Comment: And why not write a few extension methods for any of those missing methods that you feel you really need?

Comment: @PeterMajeed I'm working with older office versions. And type missing is nessesary as the API does not provide any other methods (as far as I know).

Comment: @PeterMajeed That's what a framework is for. This is like asking, why don't you write your own framework :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [VSTO Power Tools extension libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263100.aspx?pr=blog). Download [VSTO_PTExtLibs.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/3/353b1b84-828b-432b-b00f-ad70179aecd6/VSTO_PTExtLibs.exe) from [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7805). They provide [**extension methods**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for making interop with the Office API simpler.

Answer (score 1):

First version of my [Templater](http://templater.info/) library was a wrapper around MS Office and OpenOffice API calls. I too was disgusted by it's API.

There are lots of reporting frameworks, event free ones that you can probably use. Microsoft's OpenXML SDK is probably the most popular one.

Answer (score 1):

@Jake Ginnivan has written library [VSTO Contrib](http://vstocontrib.codeplex.com/) with lot of helper classes in it.